# pyspark How can I collect together values without using combineByKey or any reduce?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to implement my own simpler function than combineByKey which will basically just take in a function and an iterator and return key value pairs withh the function applied.

For example:
If I have rdd that looks like this: ([("x", 2), ("y", 1), ("x", 3)]) and a function that multiplies values together. I want to plug these both into my newly created function called collector and get this in return ([("x", 6), ("y", 1)]).

I want to make it as simple as possible but this is my first time coding in pyspark so I am not too sure how to start this.

Comment: use` groupByKey` which will return you the iterator over your groupedValues.

Comment: why not reduceByKey and just multiply there?

Comment: @Urban48 They actually both use combineBykey which is what I am trying to avoid :(

Comment: @Pankaj-Arora this uses combineBykey too which is what I am trying to avoid :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `partitionbykey` over `PairRDD` and call `mappartitions` and supply your function.

`partitionebykey` ensures same keys present in same partitions.